# grep can not match regular expression with a date whose type is character

Tags: r, regex, string, date

```
pattern<-"[0-9][0-9]\\.[0-9][0-9]\\.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])"
    grepl(pattern,"10.06.2011")
[1] FALSE
```

I am trying to match them and want it to return TRUE, I also tried pattern with dd\., however unsuccessful.

What should I do?

Comment: could also be `pattern<-"[0-9]{2}\\.[0-9]{2}\\.[0-9]{4}"`

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `)` at the end of the pattern and it will work:

```
pattern<-"[0-9][0-9]\\.[0-9][0-9]\\.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"
grepl(pattern, "10.06.2011")
# [1] TRUE
```

By the way, the pattern can be simplified to

```
"(?:\\d{2}\\.){2}\\d{4}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You do need to remove the closing parenthesis at the end of your pattern, also you can simplify this.

```
grepl("\\d{2}\\.\\d{2}\\.\\d{4}", "10.06.2011")
```